# Test login protected page with permissions in django (pytest)

Tags: python, django, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to test a view which only shows a template thus far. To access the view the user needs the permission `'projects.can_view'`.

I am trying to create a user with this permission in the test db using a fixture, then I am trying to log a client in with the username and password of my user in the db. I try to visit the view but I get a 302 error (redirect to login view.) I can verify that I actually pass the permissions correctly:

My fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def create_users_with_permissions():
    User = get_user_model()
    u = User.objects.create(
        username="test",
        password="pass",
    )

    permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view project')
    u.user_permissions.add(permission)
    u = User.objects.get(username='test')
    print(u.has_perm('appname.view_project'))
    return u
```

I query the user again to delete the permissions cache like explained in the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/). When I print out `print(u.has_perm('appname.view_project'))` it returns `True`. Thus I assume I have a user with this specific permission created.

Now I pass the fixture to my test and log pytests client-fixture in:

```
    def test_xyz(
        self, client, create_users_with_permissions
    ):

        client.login(
            username=create_users_with_permissions.username,
            password=create_users_with_permissions.password
        )
        url = reverse('urlforview')
        response = client.get(url)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

This fails with  error code: `assert 302 == 200`

If I create a superuser in the db and log in with the respective user it works. When I hardcode username and password it also fails. What am I missing here?

Thanks for every help or suggestion, very much appreciated!

My view only has this:

```
class ProjectCustomerList(PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    permission_required = 'projects.can_view'
```

Comment: `client.get(url, follow=True)`?

Comment: thanks @hoefling!! Well this gives me the error ``django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html
``. It is true that I have not yet build this template (since I am still using djangos admin login), but it shouldn't redirect me there in the first place right? It should redirect me to the correct URL since I am authenticated.....

Comment: Ah, another thing to check is whether `create_users_with_permissions.password` is a plaintext password - probably only the hash.

Comment: But let's say I hardcode it like this: ``u = User.objects.create(
        username="testuser123",
        password="mypersonalpassword",
    )`` I still get the same error..... Or do I have to do that differently?

Comment: IIRC the password is stored hashed, so `u.password` is not plaintext. When logging in, you should also pass the password plaintext, e.g. `client.login(username=u.username, password="mypersonalpassword")`

Comment: Sorry when I'm slow here, but when I do ```client.login(
            username=create_users_with_permissions.username,
            password='mypersonalpassword'
        )```. I still get the same error. This was what you meant, correct?